# Unhandled rejection Error: A model cannot be destroyed without a "where" clause or an idAttribute

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using bookshelf.js and trying to delete some registers.

My code:

```
 bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName : "campaign_target_interests" 
 //campaign.id = 3
 }).collection({campaign : campaign.id}).invokeThen('destroy').then(function(){
    console.log('Deleted');
 })
```

But it returns me the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: A model cannot be destroyed without a "where" clause or an idAttribute.
```

What can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but does it work?

```
 bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName : "campaign_target_interests" 
 //campaign.id = 3
 }).where({campaign : campaign.id}).invokeThen('destroy').then(function(){
    console.log('Deleted');
 })
```